# Python linux - listen to an opened terminal stdout

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Suppose i have some opened terminal that works independently from my python script. Is it possible to listen to this terminal stdout in some way?

Comment: If you launch this terminal from within the Python script via `subprocess` module, you can read and write through the correlated PIPE. Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html for more information.

Comment: Yeah I know this, but the terminal i want to listen to is independent from the python script.

Comment: I don't think you can, then. If the process started elsewhere, you can't hook to its streams, it would be like hijacking.

Comment: ok i understand

Comment: @omEchan if you have access to that terminal, you could [replicate its stdout to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145651/using-exec-and-tee-to-redirect-logs-to-stdout-and-a-log-file-in-the-same-time), then make your Python script continuously read that file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact process you need to capture, you may use the `strace`.

Suppose that you have two terminal.
From 1st terminal, run the `ping` command.

`ping google.com`

```
PING google.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from muc11s14-in-f14.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=11.5 ms
64 bytes from muc11s14-in-f14.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=10.9 ms
64 bytes from muc11s14-in-f14.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=11.3 ms
64 bytes from muc11s14-in-f14.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=11.4 ms
...
```

Now switch to 2nd terminal and run:
`strace -e trace=write -s1000 -fp $(pgrep ping)`

```
strace: Process 765549 attached
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=11.4 ms\n", 91) = 91
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=11.2 ms\n", 91) = 91
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=6 ttl=116 time=11.3 ms\n", 91) = 91
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=7 ttl=116 time=11.5 ms\n", 91) = 91
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx8): icmp_seq=8 ttl=116 time=11.4 ms\n", 91) = 91
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=9 ttl=116 time=11.5 ms\n", 91) = 91
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=10 ttl=116 time=11.3 ms\n", 92) = 92
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=11 ttl=116 time=11.5 ms\n", 92) = 92
...
```

At this point, we have the output of the other terminal. Let's go to the python part.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, check_output
import shlex

process_id = check_output(shlex.split("pgrep ping"), text=True).strip()

p = Popen(
    shlex.split("strace -e trace=write -s1000 -fp {0}".format(process_id)),
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, text=True
)
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line.strip())
```

Iterating the `p.stdout`, you will get the other terminal's process output.

```
strace: Process 765549 attached
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=732 ttl=116 time=11.4 ms\n", 93) = 93
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=733 ttl=116 time=11.3 ms\n", 93) = 93
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=734 ttl=116 time=11.4 ms\n", 93) = 93
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=735 ttl=116 time=11.5 ms\n", 93) = 93
write(1, "64 bytes from ber01s08-in-f238.1e100.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=736 ttl=116 time=11.3 ms\n", 93) = 93
```